# Change patterns of bars in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

How to change the pattern of the last column ?
Here is the script:

```
set ylabel "Accuracy"
set style fill solid border
set style line 1 lt 1 lc rgb "blue"
set style line 2 lt 1 lc rgb "green"
plot "orientation.csv" u (column(0)):2:(0.5):($2!=0.875?1:2) title "" w boxes lc variable fs pattern 1;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no option `fillstyle variable`. You must split the plot command in two parts: one for each pattern:

```
set boxwidth 0.5 absolute
unset key
set style fill solid border
set style line 1 lt 1 lc rgb "blue"
set style line 2 lt 1 lc rgb "green"
plot "orientation.csv" u 0:($2 != 0.875 ? $2 : 1/0) with boxes ls 1 fs pattern 1,\
     "" u 0:($2 != ? 1/0 : $2) with boxes ls 2 fs pattern 2
```

Comment: Ok, fixed in the edited answer. The `set style data boxes` doesn't seem to work with `fill...`, but requires an explicit `with boxes`.